# Why can't you use href in an <o> or <k> tag?

Tags: html, css

So I found out recently that just like

> ```
> <p> and <a>
> ```

you can use your own like

> ```
>  <o> and <k>
> ```

and style them in a css sheet by just using

> ```
> o {} and k {}
> ```

which is pretty cool but unlike

> ```
> <a> which you can href to <a href="url"></a>
> ```

you can't do this with

> ```
> <o> because <o href="url"></o> just doesn't work, even when adding the styling for cursor hover and o:focus {etc..} and o:hover {etc..}
> ```

Could anyone explain why? I got around it by using spans but it would be cool to be able to use any combination of letters for custom tags which have href functionality

Comment: Attributes generally only have default meaning in the context of a specific tag, as defined in [the HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/). They could be given custom meaning by JavaScript or CSS, but you usually want to leave links alone because the browser and accessibility programs have so much specific logic for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stay away from defining your own tags. XML offers users the ability to define their own tags, while HTML (especially HTML5) wants the user to use the pre-defined tags consistently.

The reason why you can't use href on just anything you like is because HTML just doesn't allow it. You use `<a>`s when placing links, `<span>`s to style certain word(s) of a text.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp

Comment: damn that's a bummer but oh well, it just means that if I want to style a link differently from my default <'a'> tag I have to use span and set the onclick location which is more to write than just href. Thanks a lot

Comment: You can just style a href. You can also add id's and classes to HTML objects. Check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

Comment: oh my god you can assign classes to id's? So I can just do <'p id="etc.."'>etc..</'p'> and just style #etc... {} ??

Comment: Check your formatting. Your `<a>`'s are being eaten. You need to enclose them in backticks.

Comment: trivia: Defining your own tags is a bit of a grey area right now, but it's *going* to be standardized eventually. Most browser vendors are working on the [Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements) specification now, though it'll take some time to stabilize. However, it still won't allow you to add new attributes to existing elements.

Comment: @lopu You can't assign classed to ids, but you _can_ assign _styles_ to _elements_ with ids, yes. (Or without ids, even.) And by the way, the reason you can style non-existent elements, but not assign hrefs to them is because styling is a CSS thing; CSS doesn't care about tag names. Links are a HTML thing, and HTML does! Oh, by the way, `<a>` does have built in styles of its own, but you can override those in your stylesheet. Just write `text-decoration:none` to get rid of the underline, and things like that.

Comment: @JeremyBanks The currently fashionable method for creating custom tags seems to be to use namespaces.

Comment: @MrLister Facebook uses XML namespaces, yeah. That might be required to play nice with existing validators. Custom Elements aren't going to require those, but will require a hyphenated prefix in the element name instead. Maybe one day we'll have `<fb-like>` instead of `<fb:like>`.

Answer (score 1):

For the simple reason that if you define a "custom" element like this:

```
<o href="url">go to page x</o>
```

you probably mean a behavior like this:

```
<a href="url">go to page x</a>
```

But what we are "supposing" can't be simply "predicted" by the browser; so, basically, the browser wouldn't know how to manage those attributes which you are giving to your custom tag...

Indeed, when you use something like `<o>...</o>` "tag" you are NOT defining a REAL custom tag; you are just placing a markup: whose regard the browser is simply "trasparent" (indeed doesn't do anything) just shows what is inside (if "showable") as if the "custom tag" wasn't there (we might say a "null" inline element). It can be managed, of course, trought CSS and Javascript that will specify the rest...

To build a real custom element you should place it in the register trought Javascript, with a specific sintax for the name, defining (trought Javascript) attributes and behavoirs...

Comment: Oh alright so that's why putting a class in it still works. Can you just do <'class="etc.."'></> without any tag to style something or?